# What factors to evaluate in a bank or credit union when investing certificate of deposits in the US?

Tags: united-states, banking, certificate-of-deposit, credit-unions

How do I evaluate a bank or credit union for its financial strength and trustworthiness before investing in their certificate of deposits in the US?

Comment: What country? A CD bought through a federally insured bank is insured up to $250,000.

Comment: (That's a US federally insured bank. And that's per bank, so  if you're putting more than that into. CDs  you can just spread it across multiple banks.)

Comment: This is based on the US, my bad

Comment: Google “bank solvency ratings”.

Comment: The Fed is pretty strict about bank solvency, though, so I wouldn’t worry about that.  Convenience and “good enough” yields are the things to look for.  I like Ally Bank, but there are others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How do I evaluate a bank or credit union for its financial strength
> and trustworthiness before investing in their certificate of deposits?

This is a Unites States based answer.

Step 1: verify that the bank has FDIC coverage, or the credit union has NCUA coverage.

Step 2: Make sure that the "CD" they are selling is of a type with the FDIC/NCUA coverage. Sometimes they offer a financial product that doesn't have that coverage.

Step 3: Check that this CD plus all the other deposits will be below the $250,000 maximum coverage. Note if you have multiple accounts (you, spouse, joint account, children's account, retirement accounts), the coverage is $250K for each account.

If the bank or credit union was to Fail, then the FDIC/NCUA coverage will make you whole.

If the CD will take you over the maximum coverage, then find another bank or credit union to buy the CD from.

Comment: This does not answer the solvency question.

Comment: The FDIC coverage protects you. If the bank fails the FDIC moves in and refunds your money. most of the time they arrange for another bank to absorb the failed bank and their customers.

Comment: The coverage is not per account, it's per account title holder. All the accounts with the same titled owner would be grouped together for the insurance.

Comment: That I why I listed 5 different "protected accounts": person x, person y, joint, child, retirement.

Comment: But “it has FDIC insurance” only says that they mitigate the risks to deposit holders.  OP wants to know how to make sure he doesn’t need to rely on FDIC insurance.

Comment: @RonJohn: there is no simple answer to that beyond "If concerned, research the company."

Comment: And the way to do that is google “bank solvency ratings”.

Comment: @RonJohn: If you want that in an Answer, write an Answer.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep For "Make sure that the "CD" they are selling is of a type with the FDIC coverage. Sometimes they offer a financial product that doesn't have that coverage.", does the bank being FDIC insured means all the CD the bank is selling is automatically of a type with FDIC coverage?

Comment: For most banks the CDs they sell are FDIC insured. Sometimes they have ones that don't have that coverage, but have  3rd party insurance coverage so that you are protected above the 250K limit discussed in the answer. If it doesn't have the coverage they should make that clear, but it doesn't hurt to ask.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep why do the banks have 3rd party insurance coverage so that clients are protected above the $250K limit? Isn't $250K is already the max amount the bank is willing to cover for each account title holder?

Comment: if you have less than 250K, then you are covered by the FDIC insurance. But if they can convince you to keep more money in their bank, then they might offer additional coverage via the 3ed party insurance. From my credit union: "Balances greater than $250,000 receive up to $250,000 in additional coverage through Excess Share Insurance Corporation, at no cost to you"

Comment: +1. It is unnecessary to evaluate the solvency of banks in the US. No depositor has lost a penny of FDIC-insured funds since FDIC was founded in 1933. [source: bankrate.com](https://www.bankrate.com/banking/list-of-failed-banks/)

Answer (score 4):

The main factors are interest rate, duration, convenience, and what else I would want to use that bank for. For practical purposes, US banks are pretty interchangable.

(There *may* be subtleties that you want to consider -- politics, social-good policies, that sort of thing -- but those are entirely personal preferences and very few people bother to consider them.)

Comment: This does not answer the solvency question.

Comment: Solvency, for a US bank, shouldn't be a question for any normal purchaser of CDs, given required FDIC insurance. If you would trust them with a savings account you can trust them with a CD.

Comment: *That* should have been the answer.

Comment: The question was what factors to evaluate. That's a factor to ignore, so I left as implied by "us banks are interchangable". If a different thad been asked I might have handled it differently. Feel free to write an answer phrased as you think appropriate.